# When to switch from SQLite to MySQL in production?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I am developing a web application in Django. My application is already up, and some users are are using it (say about 5-10). The database is SQLite. Should I move to MySQL now?

Or, wait till the user base increases? I don't have any user registration feature, yet. The basic usage of app is - problems are served n users solve them.

Answer (score 3):

Move now. It'll be a pain to move later. At least right now if you take your website offline for a few hours it won't be noticeable. Later, that will be a problem. (Not to mention, you'll probably have to write a script to move data from your SQLite database to MySQL, which is a pain in the ass in and of itself.)

Comment: thanks.What about dev environment? Should I continue with Sqlite? I will add problems on my dev machine, n then run the scripts on live server.

Comment: I agree with Macarse; you should use the same DBMS for development and production, for consistency.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get why using SQLite for development and then deploying it with MySQL.

Why don't develop and deploy the same RDMS?

Comment: I absolutely agree. It's not as if it's hard to install MySql on a development machine. I was bitten by inconsistencies several times before I started using the same db for both.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely move to MySQL now - on both development and production (and staging?).  The earlier you do it, the less users you disrupt and the smaller and simpler the migration will be.

Do it on development first so you see what problems you're going to run into, and resolve them before migrating to production.  If you were to keep using SQLite for development, and MySQL for production - you would run into problems with the differences eventually.